# How do I define and use a merged framework?

Tags: xcode-mergeable-libraries

I am experimenting with the [Mergeable Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-your-project-to-use-mergeable-libraries) feature introduced in Xcode 15.

I have two existing dynamic frameworks which I've marked as mergeable libraries, i.e. I've set the `MERGEABLE_LIBRARY` build setting of these two frameworks to `YES`. Let's call these two frameworks `MergeableFramework1` and `MergeableFramework2`.

I've created a new dynamic framework which (1) links to `MergeableFramework1` and `MergeableFramework2` and (2) has a `MERGED_BINARY_TYPE` build setting value of `manual`. Let's call this framework `MergedFramework`.

I've created an app which links to `MergedFramework`. I can import the `MergedFramework` module in the app's source files and the app builds fine. However, when I try to use any of the classes defined in `MergeableFramework1` or `MergeableFramework2`, I get a build error telling me that the class cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I define and use a merged library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted my error thanks to a colleague.

I need to continue linking the app to `MergedFramework` as I'm doing. However, in the app's source files, I need to import `MergeableFramework1` and `MergeableFramework2` as needed and not `MergedFramework` ‍♂️

### Addendum

I've learnt since posting my question that I don't need to change the `MERGEABLE_LIBRARY` build setting of `MergeableFramework1` and `MergeableFramework2` to `YES`. It's enough just to set the `MERGED_BINARY_TYPE` build setting of `MergedFramework` to `automatic`.